# Laravel 5 - Updating model does not update relationships immediately

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5

I ran into an interesting issue today while trying to update a model with a simple hasOne relationship.  I was doing the following:

```
public function update(MyRequest $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $data = $request->all(); //has a client_id
    $project->update($data);
    return $project->client; //Project model holds this hasOne relationship
}
```

The issue is that `$project->client` returned from the `update` function is still the old version of the client.  Shouldn't the `$project->update(...)` refresh those relationships?  The code that we have working now is:

```
public function update(MyRequest $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $data = $request->all(); //has a client_id
    $client = Client::find($data['client_id']);
    $project->update($data);
    $project->client()->associate($client);
    return $project->client; //Project model holds this hasOne relationship
}
```

At this point we are all good.  So, is the later version of the function the correct way to do this (IE get a refreshed version of the client object)?

Comment: Why you do no try the push() method described here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete - Saving A Model And Relationships. Also check this note there: Note: No model events are fired when updating a set of models via the Eloquent query builder. $project->update($data); $project->push();

Comment: You can refresh your project model with the [fresh()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fresh) method like so:

`$project = $project->fresh();`

Comment: In Laravel 5.1 it appears like push() is being deprecated.  It's not in the docs anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Just save the model after updating:

```
$project->update($data);
$project->save();

return $project->client;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$project->update($data);
$project->save();

return $project->client;
```

This will not return updated client,

to get the updated client, you need to refresh the model,

```
$project->update($data);
$project->save();
$project = $project->fresh();

return $project->client;
```

Now you will get updated client